# Rails scaffold without the css file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, scaffold

Is there a way to generate a scaffold in rails 3.0 so that scaffold.css does NOT get created? Something at the command line I can enter to skip that step?

Thanks

Answer (score 69, accepted):

There is a `--no-stylesheets` flag you can use:

```
rails g scaffold MyModel --no-stylesheets
```

Comment: NOTE: this will also disabling resource specific stylesheets, i.e. `app/assets/stylesheets/my_model.css.scss` won't be created

Comment: Utilizing `--no-stylesheets` is a good idea if your app uses Twitter Bootstrap, because the `scaffold.css` file that Rails generates overrides quite a few of Bootstrap's styles.

Answer (score 47):

You can also disable it by default -- in `config/application.rb`:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.stylesheets false
end
```

Rails itself only uses it for `scaffold.css` AFAIK, but unfortunately the same hook could be used by other generators, so you might need to remember to pass `--stylesheets` for a third-party gem that generates assets, for instance. It'd be really nice if Rails had an explicit option for `scaffold.css` :-/

You can find other generator options [in the Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-generators), by the way. Helpers are nice to turn off by default and generate them when you actually want them.

Comment: rails has an option to specifically disable the scaffold.css: ```g.scaffold_stylesheet false```

Comment: Thanks @eikes, fairly certain that setting didn't exist in Rails 3 days but if the question/tags are updated for current versions I'll happily give your answer my vote.

Answer (score 11):

Since Rails 5.0, there is a configuration in `config/application.rb` which specifically disables generating the `app/assets/stylesheets/scaffolds.css`, but still generates the stylesheets for your new resource:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.scaffold_stylesheet false
end
```

You can also pass it in as the `--no-scaffold-stylesheet` command line option:

```
rails generate scaffold post title body:text --no-scaffold-stylesheet
```