# How do I prevent scaffold.css from overriding my custom css?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css

I can't figure it out. It's probably trivial but I am extremely new to rails.

Thanks in advance if you can help!

Answer:

I went to the generated file that adds the header to my pages and changed the included css file to my own custom one.

Comment: So how did you solve your problem?

Comment: You can apply order inclusion rules to your css inclusion - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890929/rails-3-1-load-css-in-particular-order for ideas.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 3.1 it would work a litte bit different since only the application style is included by default.

Since there is a list of all further included ones like mentioned here: [Rails 3.1 Load css in particular order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890929/rails-3-1-load-css-in-particular-order), you just have to change the order of this list or add the file at a specific position.

Answer (score -1):

There's a question about not using scaffold.css, might be what you're looking for?

[Rails scaffold without the css file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966776/rails-scaffold-without-the-css-file)

Comment: What about "rails g scaffold MyModel --no-stylesheets" isn't obvious?

Answer (score -1):

It's not the most beautiful css, but in css you can add '!important' after an statement to override all 'normal' css statements. So you would use something along the lines of:

```
border:0px !important;
```

in your css.

Comment: Don't use `!important` for trivial things like this. Change the load order of the CSS instead.

Comment: Load order has only something to do with rules of equal specificity, as I already pointed out in the answer it's not  beautiful CSS, but in cases where you're stuck with framework css it sometimes makes most sense.

Comment: And either way it's a good option to be aware of, not like `!important` is evil, just another (ugly) way to affect specificity.

Answer (score -1):

Have the CSS file with the correct styling you want applied to load last.

Or as others have suggested you could add !important to the css in question if you cant change the load order of the css files.

```
body {
color:#FFFFFF!important;
}
```