# Rails scaffolds scss reset each time a scaffold is generated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sass, scaffolding

Each time I do a `rails generate scaffold Name`, the `app/assets/stylesheets/scaffolds.css.scss` file is overwritten (well I get prompted to overwrite it). I don't want this, so of course I could just type `n` when prompted to overwrite, but I want to know the proper way to handle styling of scaffolds.

I could just write the css in a css file loaded later to override the necessary css in the scaffolds.css.scss file. But not only is that ugly (have unnecessary/unused css being generated and loaded every request), but I don't know how to not change the foreground and background colors upon hovering over links (from scaffolds.css.scss):

```
a {
  &:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
  }
}
```

What's the proper way to remove something like the above from `scaffolds.css.scss`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966776/rails-scaffold-without-the-css-file)

`rails g scaffold MyModel --no-stylesheets`

Comment: So to change stylesheets for scaffolds, we are supposed to modify scaffolds.css.scss and then just not generate the stylesheets for scaffolds?

Comment: I think it's a bit of a discussion, but scaffolding is considered great for rapid prototyping. Once you're set with the models or have a good start, you can modify the code or start from scratch if you know what you want. More discussion [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/75011/do-experienced-ruby-on-rails-developers-use-scaffolding)

Comment: My question was about the proper way to modify stylesheets for scaffolds (which seem to get included in all webpages in Rails by default too), not when and whether scaffolding is useful.

Answer (score 18):

Want to disable disable stylesheet forever, or usually forgot `--no-stylesheets` switch(I DO!)

**Disable stylesheet in your generator!!**

config/application.rb

```
config.generators do |g|
 g.stylesheets false
end
```

Comment: This is documented at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#customizing-your-workflow

Comment: Yes but, its possible to generate the resource css but not the scaffold css?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that you can always redefine these things in your own stylesheets, and include them later than the scaffolding stylesheets by modifying assets/stylesheets/application.css

```
 *= require_self
 *= require scaffolds
 *= require YOUR_FILE
```

(If you don't fiddle with application.css, by default the stylesheets get included in alphabetical order, which may or may not be what you want.)