# Stop scaffold generates scafolds.css.scss

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails 4

And refered these solutions by not works for me

[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966776/rails-scaffold-without-the-css-file)

Run scaffold by

```
rails g scaffold Tool::Mvaas::P2pQuery   --no-stylesheets user_id:integer interval:integer
```

But still generated `scaffolds.css.scss` for me

```
   conflict    app/assets/stylesheets/scaffolds.css.scss
  Overwrite /Users/hsu-wei-cheng/workspace/Rails/dqa_dev_server/app/assets/stylesheets/scaffolds.css.scss?
```

Answer (score 3):

Update

You can disable scaffold stylesheet placing this code on the file config/initializers/assets.rb:
`Rails.application.config.generators do |g|
  g.scaffold_stylesheet false
end`

Answer (score 1):

read [this guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html) chapter "3.3 Configuring Generators".

Place into `config/application.rb` this code

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.stylesheets false
end
```